# jOOQ fetch multiple records

Tags: postgresql, jooq, multiple-records

I want to fetch a set of records from db where a field matches multiple values ( the count of which cant be predetermined ) . To exemplify,

```
Tables.A.ID.in(Set of IDs)
Tables.A.ID.notIn(Set of IDs)
```

I went through the documentation of fetchMany and fetchAny [ResultQuery Documentation](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.3.2/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchMany()). I tried implementing it , but with no success.

I want to fetch all rows in DB which match the "Set of IDs" where IDs are NOT UNIQUE.

I am not able to understand how to use 'in' and 'notIn' in my pretext. Could someone show me with an example how to fetch the Set of Resulting Records from the database.

Comment: *"I tried implementing it , but with no success."* Can you show what you tried? In particular, you should probably just call [`ResultQuery.fetch()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetch--), not `fetchMany()` or `fetchAny()`

Comment: yes.. thats what i was looking for. could you also tell me the use of fetchMany and fetchAny .. there are no good examples to illustrate the use for them... thanks!! @LukasEder

Comment: I'll be more than happy to illustrate use-cases if you ask new questions, as I think that such an answer might not fit into this question here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect, you're simply looking for this?

```
Set<Integer> setOfIDs = ...

Result<Record> result = 
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select()
   .from(A)
   .where(A.ID.in(setOfIDs))
   .fetch();
```